# ionic - firebase notification using PHP not working

Tags: php, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugin-fcm

I want to push notification to my Ionic 2 app using firebase. I can push notification directly using firebase console, but I want to send it via php file.

when I send I get a response from PHP as: `{"message_id":5718309985299480645}`

And there is no notification in the phone.

I have placed `this.fcm.subscribeToTopic('all')` in the app.component.ts constructor.

I dont know what I am doing wrong..

`this.fcm.subscribeToTopic('all')` is the only code related to fcm in my app.

MY PHP CODE:

```
<?php 

   $data = array('title'=>'FCM Push Notifications');
   $target = '/topics/mytopic';


   //FCM API end-point
   $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
   //api_key available in Firebase Console -> Project Settings -> CLOUD MESSAGING -> Server key
   $server_key = 'my_server_key_from_firebase';

   $fields = array();
   $fields['data'] = $data;
   if(is_array($target)){
   $fields['registration_ids'] = $target;
   }else{
   $fields['to'] = $target;
   }

   //header with content_type api key
   $headers = array(
   'Content-Type:application/json',
   'Authorization:key='.$server_key
   );
   //CURL request to route notification to FCM connection server (provided by Google)           
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
   $result = curl_exec($ch);
   if ($result === FALSE) {
   die('Oops! FCM Send Error: ' . curl_error($ch));
   }
   curl_close($ch);
   echo $result;

?>
```

I EVEN TRIED PUSHBOTS BUT COULD NOT GET NOTFICATIONS ON THE DEVICE WITH PHP

Comment: I don't see you setting a priority or click_action, Are you following the payload like in the end of this page?: https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm

Comment: what is FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY?

Comment: Never bothered looking for this since it's a default for using pushs in Android with FCM, but i think it's the defaullt behaviour of a push, like the one discribed in "how it works" bellow the payload explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem by looking at [fcm docs](https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm#send-notification-payload-example-rest-api).

I changed the PHP file to:

```
   $data = array('title'=>'Title of the notification', 'body'=>$msg, 'sound'=>'default');
   $target = '/topics/notetoall';

   $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

   $server_key = 'my_server_api_key_from_firebase';

   $fields = array();
   $fields['notification'] = $data; // <-- this is what I changed from $fields['body']
   if(is_array($target)){
   $fields['registration_ids'] = $target;
   }else{
   $fields['to'] = $target;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

All plugins must be called after the device ready, specially if they're beeing used in `app.components` (in some pages, that are not the first one, it can be used inside constructor since the app is already ready and plugins are loaded).

So subscribe to a topic on device ready

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  this.fcm.subscribeToTopic('all')
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, I tried this solutions, this works if I send from firebase console but not from php. I have pasted the PHP code in the question, Please check.

Comment: Oh, this is something different, your question was about where to place the FCM plugin call. Since you edited i'll take a look

Comment: did you have look at my PHP file?